# Turn on and off ssh access to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want the EC2 to be accessible only through session manager.

Originally I launched one, ssh into it, installed the ssm-manager, but then I found out I can't replace its ENI with a non-public-facing ENI.

So then I tried launching one with an ENI with only a private IP, associate a public EIP to it, but I fail to ssh into the machine, it keeps timing out.

After quite a lot of experimenting around I just can't find the solution to this problem, so here I am.

What do I need?
I want to know how to create an EC2 instance that has NO PUBLIC IP and NO PUBLIC SUBNET.
Attach a public IP to it and config it to work
SSH into it, install SSM agent
and then disable ALL PUBLIC FACING networking.

any suggestions? guides?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an AMI that has the SSM agent already installed and configured, or pick one of the existing AMIs that have SSM agent pre-installed. Then launch your EC2 instances from that AMI.

Comment: How do I know if SSM is preinstalled on it?

Comment: Most of the standard Linux and Windows AMIs provided by Amazon have the agent pre-installed. I'm not aware of a list providing those details though. You would have to try an AMI and see what is on it. I know all the latest Amazon Linux AMIs have it pre-installed.

Comment: I've tried several of the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS AMIs. They have it installed, but it's nto working. I still need to ssh into it and run it on using systemctl.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to add `user-data` to get it to startup when the instance boots?

Comment: NVM, I eventually found an AMI of ubuntu 22.04 that had a session manager working.
Thanks for the patience!